# Wro4j imports not working after some refreshes

Tags: wro4j

So I have a pretty big application with a lot of imports. Third party js libraries and a lot of angular code.

Now I glued them all together with wro4j into two big files that are compressed.

The order in which I did it is correct as the application works as intended. But often times when I press F5 to reload the page, stuff will break. JS console will start throwing errors and some style settings get lost on the page. But at the same time when I look at the source code, everything is still there. Angular tells about missing modules that are all there and the css that is broken... well the correct css is also in one file and correctly loaded into the page source code.

Has anyone experienced something like this? How would you debug this?

Comment: Could you create a quick-start project which would help to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Dont think so. Its a job project where I am trying to use wro4j in. We have like over 150 javascript files atleast that need to be compressed. Problem is that wro4j randomly does not included some files from time to time. It can be a css file or a js file. And the files that dont get included are completely random every time.

Comment: I have updated the issue with a comment: disable parallel pre processing flag.